# Assembly output of the register

Tags: assembly, x86

How can I get the output of theregisters:
If we suppose CX=5,AX=0,DX=10,BX=0

a.

```
Not CX

Cmp CX,DX

JL jump1

Mov BX,1

Jmp skip1

Jump1:

Mov ax,10

Skip1:

Ret
```

After execution in hexadecimal: ax=?
BX=? ,CX=?

B.

```
Org 100h

Mov CX,9

Mov AL,2H

Camp AL,05H

JB label1

Sub AL,03H

Jmp exit 

Label1:

Mov CX,3

Exit:

Ret
```

After execution in hexadecimal: AL=?
 ,CX=?

C.

```
Org 100h

Mov BX,20H

Mov AL,0FFH  ;CF=0

Add AL,1

JC label1

Mov BX,6

Label1:

Mov BX,7

Exit:

Ret
```

After execution in hexadecimal: AL=?
BX=?

Someone explain this please

Comment: Nope, have a shot on it on your own *first*.

Comment: We're not doing the homework for you.

Comment: Simulate the execution of instructions by yourself by hand or using emulator tool such as Bochs.

Comment: Steal the answer off the student next to you.

Answer (score 2):

Write it down in a tabular form, then fill in the blanks:

```
            AX=0    BX=0    CX=5    DX=10
-----------------------------------------
Not CX      0       0       -6      10     Not inverses the bits of CX

Cmp CX,DX   0       0       -6      10     -6 is less than 10 ...

JL jump1    0       0       -6      10     ... so this jump is taken!

Mov BX,1

Jmp skip1

Jump1:

Mov ax,10

Skip1:
```

Make your way down these lists, then write down the result in hexadecimal.

If some *individual instruction* troubles you, ask us about it.

Answer (score 0):

[Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) is useful for simulating.

#### How to use:

1. Assemble the source adjusted and added some charms to run with [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/).

Code:

```
bits 16
head:

not cx
cmp cx, ax
jl jump1
mov bx, 1
jmp skip1
jump1:
mov ax, 10
skip1:
ret

; to make this image bootable
times 510-($-head) db 0
db 0x55
db 0xaa
```

2. Lanuch Bochs. Use debug-enabled version such as `bochsdbg-win64.exe`.
3. set `Disk & Boot` setting like this (Other tabs are default values):
   [image: disk setting for bochs]
   The `First floppy image/device` should be the image assembled by step 1.
4. set `ROM BIOS image` and `VGA BIOS image` in `Memory` setting properly.
   If file `BIOS-bochs-latest` and `VGABIOS-lgpl-latest` are in the working directory, just enter them (remove `(null)/`)
5. Start simulation by pressing `Start` button.
6. Enter `lb 0x7c00` (set breakpoint at linear address `0x7c00`) then `c` (continue) to the console to skip BIOS intialization and jump and stop at the beginning of user code.
7. Set the values of registers using `set` command.

Say:

```
set cx = 5
set ax = 0
set dx = 10
set bx = 0
```

8. `reg` command is available to view values of registers.
   `s` command is available to execute one instruction.
   Use them to observe what the program does.

Sample result for the first program:
[image: result for the first program]